# Php files attached and not attached statment

Tags: php

I have a code

```
if(count($_FILES) > 0) {
    foreach($_FILES['fileAttach']['error'] as $status){
        if($status === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $fname[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'][$Ccount];
        $tmp_path[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'][$Ccount];
        $ftype[] =  $_FILES['fileAttach']['type'][$Ccount];
        }
        $Ccount++;
    }
} else { $fname[] = "0"; $tmp_path[] = "0"; $ftype[] = "0"; } // this not working
```

Then i want to use variables in function

```
SendEmails($ReCEmail,$strSubject,$strMessage,$txtFormName,$txtFormEmail,$fname,$ftype,$tmp_path);
```

It works until files is attached, but if no i got error `Notice: Undefined variable: fname in ... on line ..`

```
function SendEmails($vasia,$strSubject,$strMessage,$txtFormName,$txtFormEmail,$fname,$ftypes,$tmp_path) {

if(count($fname) == 0) 
        { code without variables $fname,$ftypes,$tmp_path } 
else {code with variables $fname,$ftypes,$tmp_path}
}
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(count(array_filter($_FILES['fileAttach']['name'])) > 0) {
    foreach($_FILES['fileAttach']['error']  as $key => $status){
        if($status === 0) {
        $fname[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'][$key];
        $tmp_path[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $ftype[] =  $_FILES['fileAttach']['type'][$key];
        }
    }
} else { $fname[] = "0"; $tmp_path[] = "0"; $ftype[] = "0"; }
```

and in your function change

```
if(count(array_filter($fname)) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all $_FILES are error, then files array will be zero. So this error is printed

```
$fname[] = array();
$tmp_path[] = array();
$ftype[] = array();

    foreach($_FILES['fileAttach']['error'] as $key => $status){
        if($status === 0) {
        $fname[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'][$key];
        $tmp_path[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $ftype[] =  $_FILES['fileAttach']['type'][$key];
        }
    }

      if(count($fname)==0)
     { $fname[] = "0";$tmp_path[] = "0"; $ftype[] = "0"; }
```

Comment: Why count($_FILES) = 1 if no files is loaded?

Comment: Since you are uploading files from a form, it will send $_FILES['fileAttach'] even if you dont upload any files

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your $fname array before the if:

```
$fname = array();
if($status === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
```

Confirm that your upload process is working by putting and echo after the if:

```
if($status === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "Upload Status: " . $status . "<br>";
        $fname[] = $_FILES['fileAttach']['name'][$Ccount];
```

If the echo output shows that $status != UPLOAD_ERR_OK, then $fname was not getting initialized, hence the Undefined variable error.

If the upload is failing, create another question containing the corresponding code snippets for that issue.

Comment: what is the output of the echo in my answer?

Comment: the same echo, no differs

Comment: Are you saying that the line: echo "Upload Status: " . $status . "<br>"; outputs "Upload Status: "?  If so, this means $status is null or empty and, thus, if($status === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) would equal FALSE.  It then follows, that $fname is never initalized and that is why you are getting an Undefined variable error.

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to set the $status variable.